# Как подключить файлы в htaccess, а как запустить контроллер?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc, маршрутизация

У меня есть папки: `app`, `core`, `files`. В `app` хранится *MVC* приложение, в `core` ядро, а в `files` все пользовательские файлы и папки. Я разрабатываю свою систему и мне необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Все запросы переправлять на `/index.php`
2. Выдавать 403 на все корневые папки, чтобы пользователь не мог зайти в них
3. При обращении к файлу в `/files/*` выдавать файл.

То есть сейчас есть проблема в том, что при обращении к любой папке показывается ее структура. Вторая проблема, что если создать контроллер FilesController и обратиться к нему `/files/`, то показывается папка, а не выполняется контроллер.

Пробовал так:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

#Options +FollowSymLinks
#IndexIgnore */* 
RewriteEngine On


#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/
#RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /files/assets/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /files/assets/css/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /files/assets/js/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /files/assets/images/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule .* index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**UPD**. Вопрос закрытия доступа к `app` и `core` сделал вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:app|core)\b.* index.php [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]
```

Как вот сделать с файлами пока не знаю. У меня есть папка `files` и есть контроллер такой же. Как вот их разграничить?

Comment: Проще говоря: обратился к файлу в `files/*` - выдал файл. Обратился к любой папке - 403, обратился к контроллеру - показал результат. Вот как это сделать?

Comment: Использовать роутер с перенаправлением всех запросов на индексный файл